# How to minimize sql query

Tags: mysql

I have a `booking` table in MySQL database where I need to get 3 data.

1) Total Booking
2) Pending Booking  ( where `is_confirm = 1` )
3) Complete Booking  ( where `is_confirm = 0` )

Now, I am writing 3 separate query to get this but how can I get it using 1 query?

**current query:**

```
$booking = new Admin;
$booking->rowQuery("SELECT count(bid) AS totalBooking FROM booking");
$bookingData = $booking->result->fetch_assoc();
$totalBooking = $bookingData['totalBooking'];

$booking->rowQuery("SELECT bid FROM booking WHERE is_confirm = 1 ");
$completeBooking = $booking->rows;

$booking->rowQuery("SELECT bid FROM booking WHERE is_confirm = 0 ");
$pendingBooking = $booking->rows;
```

Comment: Have a look at `UNION`

Comment: which type of output you need explain it..?

Comment: @Dr.Strange as I have said in my question that I need to get the total number of data, complete data, and pending data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use case sql . Try this:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN is_confirm = 1 THEN 1 END) AS confirmCount,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN is_confirm = 0 THEN 1 END) AS noconfirmCount,
    COUNT(*) AS total
FROM booking;
```

Comment: Great, Working fine :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT count(bid) AS totalBooking FROM booking
UNION
SELECT bid FROM booking
WHERE is_confirm=1
UNION
SELECT bid FROM booking
WHERE is_confirm=0
```

Comment: how can I get the count of `is_confirm = 1` and `is_confirm` = 0 ? should I use `AS` in the sql query?

Comment: @Shibbir yes, you can use aliases. Updated my post.

Comment: The aliases will be lost once you perform the `union`. You'll have no way to distinguish between pending and completed bookings (or the total count for that matter).

Comment: Error showing: Undefined index: confirmed_booking.... and Undefined index: unconfirmed_booking in ....

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate functions usually skip `null`s, including [`group_concat`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat). If you don't mind [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)ing the result string later, you could use `case` expressions to get the total bookings and coma-delimited strings for the IDs:

```
SELECT COUNT(bid) AS totalBooking,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CASE is_confirm WHEN 1 THEN bid END) AS pendingBookings,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CASE is_confirm WHEN 0 THEN bid END) AS completeBookings
FROM   booking
```